# Not able to find function Marshal()

Tags: go, package, icmp

I am writing small code for generating the ICMP packet. For that I am following the code from [golang net package](https://golang.org/src/net/ipraw_test.go).

I identified the following code to use for ICMP packet generation:

```
   109          c, err := Dial(tt.net, tt.raddr)
   110          if err != nil {
   111              t.Fatalf("Dial failed: %v", err)
   112          }
   113          c.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(100 * time.Millisecond))
   114          defer c.Close()
   115  
   116          typ := icmpv4EchoRequest
   117          if net == "ip6" {
   118              typ = icmpv6EchoRequest
   119          }
   120          xid, xseq := os.Getpid()&0xffff, i+1
   121          wb, err := (&icmpMessage{
   122              Type: typ, Code: 0,
   123              Body: &icmpEcho{
   124                  ID: xid, Seq: xseq,
   125                  Data: bytes.Repeat([]byte("Go Go Gadget Ping!!!"), 3),
   126              },
   127          }).Marshal()
   128          if err != nil {
   129              t.Fatalf("icmpMessage.Marshal failed: %v", err)
   130          }
   131          if _, err := c.Write(wb); err != nil {
   132              t.Fatalf("Conn.Write failed: %v", err)
   133          }
```

I am not able to understand followings in this code :

1. `Marshal()` is not included in the [net package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/), please let me know how to find this function and why it is not included in the net package.
2. please explain me line #121 (`icmpMessage` struct and function calling as these are not defined in this file).

Comment: Please check http://golang.org/src/net/mockicmp_test.go

Comment: Thanks @Alper for the response, but why `Marshal()` is not available in net package (function name starts with capital).

Comment: That's a test code and there is no `net/icmp` package in Go. I am not sure why they chose to start with capital but `Marshal()` is a method and receiver is `*icmpMessage` (starts with lower-case `i` and unexported), therefore, `Marshal()` cannot be called even though it starts with capital.

Comment: I have a feeling these may be placeholders for future functions as they are available in http://golang.org/x/net/icmp. Still not sure why they're capitalized, except possibly to make future integration of the /x/ package into the main line easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Marshal() defined here https://golang.org/src/net/mockicmp_test.go?h=Marshal#L32
2. And icmpMessage struct here https://golang.org/src/net/mockicmp_test.go?h=icmpMessage#L17

Comment: Now `icmpMessage` struct is clear to me, otherwise I was thinking it as anonymous structs. One silly question, how did you find the file `mockicmp_test.go`. I tried in golang.org search but, I didn't able to find it.

Comment: http://golang.org/search?q=Marshal   works for me. On local machine you can do 'godoc -index true -q Marshal | grep net' or similar

Comment: @subh.singh: test files are not linked in the html docs by default. It's often easiest to just check out the go source directly, and search using local tools.